# Deploy a shiny app that sources c code via shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to use shinyapps.io to deploy a shiny app that sources c code.

Can I upload compiled c executable to shinyapps.io account and call it from the R shiny app?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading compiled C code to shinyapps.io is not likely to work unless it happens to be compiled and linked exactly as it would be on shinyapps.io (on Ubuntu Linux using the same gcc version, libc, etc).

To execute native code on shinyapps.io, the best way would be to create a small package and upload it to GitHub. Packages hosted on GitHub will automatically be detected and installed on shinyapps.io if you use `devtools::install_github` to install the package locally.

The other possability it to use the [inline](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inline/index.html) package to create an "inline" C++ function directly in you R code which is compiled when the function is called.